# comment added by the logging in user didn't properly save

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, save

I have been currently working on an easy Django website.
An error came up when I tried to implement a function that users can add comments to blogs. I succeeded to show the form where users can write their comments, but even if I pressed the add button, didn't save properly.

I don't even know where I made a mistake coz I knew how to post and save information to the database.
so, I ask you to help!!

```
# add_comment.html
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %}｜コメント追加{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="header-bar">
    <a href="{% url 'blog' blog.id %}">&#8592; 戻る</a>
  </div>
  
  <div class="body-container blog">
    <div class="body-header">
      <h1>コメント追加</h1>
    </div>
    <form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <button class='button' type="submit">追加</button>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

```
# views.py
@login_required
def add_comment(request, pk):
  blog = get_object_or_404(Blog, pk=pk)
  if request.method == 'post':
    form = CommentForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
      comment = form.save(commit=False)
      comment.blog = blog
      comment.save()
      return redirect('blog', pk=blog.pk)
  else:
    form = CommentForm()
  
  context = {
    'form': form,
  }
  return render(request, 'blog/add_comment.html', context)
```

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path 
from . import views
from .views import BlogCreate, BlogUpdate, BlogDelete, BlogList
# blogs
urlpatterns = [
  path('', views.index, name='latest_blogs'),
  path('my_blogs/', views.my_blogs, name='my_blogs'),
  path('my_blogs/my_blog_search', views.my_blogs_search, name='my_blogs_search'),
  path('drafts/', views.drafts, name='drafts'),
  path('blog/<int:pk>/', views.blog, name='blog'),
  path('blog/<int:pk>/comment/', views.add_comment, name='add_comment'),
  path('create/', BlogCreate.as_view(), name='blog-create'),
  path('update/<int:pk>/', BlogUpdate.as_view(), name='blog-update'),
  path('delete/<int:pk>/', BlogDelete.as_view(), name='blog-delete'),
  path('all_blogs/', BlogList.as_view(), name='all_blogs'),
  path('all_blogs/all_blogs_search/', views.all_blogs_search, name='all_blogs_search'),
]
```

Any comments help me and thanks for your time in advance!!

Comment: `request.method` is uppercase: `if request.method == 'POST':`

Comment: It is working right now!! Thanks!!